# Regex matching issue to Test-String

Tags: regex

i have a problem and dont get it.

My Regex:

[image: Regex]

My Test-String:

[image: Test-String]

I have two issues and one general question :)

1. As you can see in my Test-String the very last (german) Phone Number (the big yellow one in the Test-String attachment) does not match my Regex-Pattern correctly. I dont get it, what is the Problem here? the "0049" fits Group 5, but should fit Group 2, why is that?
2. My second Problem is, how can i get rid of the spaces before and after every match? (The 7 yellow small circles in the Test-String Attachment)

For copy/paste purposes, here is the Regex and Test-String again:

**Regex:**
`((\+\d{2}|00\d{2})?([ ])?(\()?(\d{2,4})(\))?([-| |/])?(\d{3,})([ ])?(\d+)?([ ])?(\d+)?)`

**Test-String:**
Vorwahl 089, die E.123 ebenfalls , also (089) 1234567. Die DIN 5008, also +49 89 1234567 respectivly 0049 89 1234567. Die E.123 empfiehlt, also +49 89 123456 0 respectivly 0049 89 123456 0 oder +49 89 123456 789. Also +49 89 123 456 789. Klammern 089/1234567 und 0151 19406041. Test +49 151 123 456 789 respectivly 0049 151 123 456 789

Last but not at least, my general question:
Is it a good approach to Group each logical part as i did in my example?

A last Information: I validate my Regex with https://regex101.com/ and use it in Python with the re Module.

Comment: Please make shure the Regex-Patterns in the screenshot and the copy-paste-one match. Some \ seem to be missing.

Comment: thx for the feedback, i fixed it.

Comment: for your issue 1, because 0049 is preceded by a space.

Comment: how to fix this? mybe issue 1 and issue 2 are related :)

Comment: By the way, `[]` is a character set which match any literal value inside, so `[-| |/]` are matching `-`, `|`,  `/` and space, you don't need `|` inside a set unless you want to match literal `|`.

Comment: ou right thanks. Thats a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that makes it unpredictable are the numerous optional groups `(..)?`.

As first step i recommend replacing `([ ])?(\d+)?` as a coupled expression `([ ]?\d+)?`, which will avoid spaces at the end of the match - your point #2.

As a second step i recommend coupling the first optional space with the expression of the "national dialling": `((\+|00)\d{2}([ ])?)?`. Now we are lucky, because it solves both the space at the beginning and the recognition of the whole number, due to less possible matching options.

The new expression now looks like this:

```
(((\+|00)\d{2}([ ])?)?(\()?(\d{2,4})(\))?([-| |/])?(\d{3,})([ ]?\d+)?([ ]?\d+)?)
```

I now recommend to simplify the last part, if you dont need the single group-values:

```
(((\+|00)\d{2}([ ])?)?(\()?(\d{2,4})(\))?([-| |/])?(\d{3,})([ ]?\d+){0,2})
```

For better performance I suggest you remove the parenteses/groups where possible or mark them as non-capturing, if you don't need to have the specific group-values.
<s>In some programming languages you will not need to most outer parenteses, as that is always group 0.</s>

Comment: Thanks al lot, this works perfectly fine for me.

"Aswell you will not need to most outer parenteses, as that is always group 0."
--> This seems to be important, because Python do not return any results if the most outer parantheses are not there.

Comment: Sorry, Python returns results, but not the whole match, but the groups as tuple. So i need the first group to be the whole match. So i need the first group as whole match so i can access it via the index 0 from the result-list

Comment: Okay, I don't know about the Python part. Edited my answer.